# I have created and installed an app using Slack CLI but it says Authentication has not been setup

Tags: authentication, command-line-interface, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Having managed to create and install a simple app to my Slack workspace, other users, including another collaborator who did not deploy it, cannot install the app, and therefore cannot call it using the slash command.

It works perfectly for me, both locally and deployed. Other users can see it added to the channel they are in, but they cannot run the workflow.

When I look in configuration it tells me that authentication is not setup, which seems odd, because if that was the case I shouldn't be able to run it.

I can't see how to distribute it to other users myself either. Anybody encountered this issue before and found a solution? What am I missing?